# how made total price

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

How can make total price for this saleresult code? in this code I wrote 2 queries, in first I fetch prices from SQL server and in the second query I fetch the selected item by the user and put price near them and show in the label. now I want to show the total price in one label but I have converting problem. what should I do?

```
 public partial class SingleSeatSaleResult : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string Fruit_price;
string Drink_price;
string Desert_price;
string MainFood_price;
string Salad_price;
string TableFlower_price;
string SaloonLighting_price;
string SaloonDesign_price;
string SaloonCrew_price;
string Pastry_price;
string GiftCard_price;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    using (SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {
        //query for fetch service prices 
        string strquery2 = "SELECT Fruit_price,Drink_price,Desert_price,MainFood_price,Salad_price,TableFlower_price,SaloonLighting_price,SaloonDesign_price,SaloonCrew_price,Pastry_price,GiftCard_price  FROM GenReservationServicePrice";
        connection2.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd2.Connection = connection2;
        cmd2.CommandText = strquery2;
        SqlDataReader reader1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader1.Read())
        {                               
            Fruit_price = reader1[0].ToString();
            Drink_price = reader1[1].ToString();
            Desert_price = reader1[2].ToString();
            MainFood_price = reader1[3].ToString();
            Salad_price = reader1[4].ToString();
            TableFlower_price = reader1[5].ToString();
            SaloonLighting_price = reader1[6].ToString();
            SaloonDesign_price = reader1[7].ToString();
            SaloonCrew_price = reader1[8].ToString();
            Pastry_price = reader1[9].ToString();
            GiftCard_price = reader1[10].ToString();

        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {          
        string strquery1 = "SELECT (select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1) as fruit, (select top 1 'Drink' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Drink=1) as drink, (select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1) as desert,(select top 1 'MainFood' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where MainFood=1) as MainFood,(select top 1 'Salad' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Salad=1) as salad,(select top 1 'TableFlower' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where TableFlower=1) as TableFlower,(select top 1 'SaloonLighting' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SaloonLighting=1) as SaloonLighting,(select top 1 'Saloondesign' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Saloondesign=1) as Saloondesign,(select top 1 'SloonCrew' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SloonCrew=1) as SloonCrew,(select top 1 'Pastry' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Pastry=1) as Pastry,(select top 1 'GiftCard' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where GiftCard=1) as GiftCard ";
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection1;
        cmd1.CommandText = strquery1;
        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        lbl2_customerid.Text = cis;


        SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader2.Read())
        {
            if (reader2[0].ToString() != null && reader2[0].ToString() != "")
            lbl8_fruit.Text = reader2[0].ToString() + Fruit_price;

            if (reader2[1].ToString() != null && reader2[1].ToString() != "")
            lbl10_drink.Text = reader2[1].ToString()+Drink_price;


            if (reader2[2].ToString() != null && reader2[2].ToString() != "")
            lbl11_desert.Text = reader2[2].ToString()+Desert_price;

            if (reader2[3].ToString() != null && reader2[3].ToString() != "")
            lbl12_mainfood.Text = reader2[3].ToString()+MainFood_price;


            if (reader2[4].ToString() != null && reader2[4].ToString() != "")
            lbl13_salad.Text = reader2[4].ToString()+Salad_price;


            if (reader2[5].ToString() != null && reader2[5].ToString() != "")
            lbl14_tableflower.Text = reader2[5].ToString()+TableFlower_price;


            if (reader2[6].ToString() != null && reader2[6].ToString() != "")
            lbl15_saloonlighting.Text = reader2[6].ToString()+SaloonLighting_price;


            if (reader2[7].ToString() != null && reader2[7].ToString() != "")
            lbl16_saloondesign.Text = reader2[7].ToString()+SaloonDesign_price;


            if (reader2[8].ToString() != null && reader2[8].ToString() != "")
            lbl17_salooncrew.Text = reader2[8].ToString()+SaloonCrew_price;


            if (reader2[9].ToString() != null && reader2[9].ToString() != "")
            lbl18_pastry.Text = reader2[9].ToString()+Pastry_price;


            if (reader2[10].ToString() != null && reader2[10].ToString() != "")
            lbl19_giftcard.Text = reader2[10].ToString()+GiftCard_price;


        }
    }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to convert price of selected items and show it in another label. 
If it so then  you have to convert the label value for price to int and sum it.

If my answer is not correct then, provide some more details.

UPDATE:
from UI,

```
var totalPrice=(int)lbl8_fruit.Text +(int)lbl10_drink.Text;
```

And if you need to calculate it from the reader, then create a list for different price and fill the list from reader.

After that,

```
var total= yourList.Sum(x=>x.Price);
```

If your string is like "10.00", then you need to convert to double.

If your string is just like "10", then

```
var totalPrice=Convert.ToInt32(lbl8_fruit.Text) +Convert.ToInt32(lbl10_drink.Text);
```

If your string have decimals just like "10.00", then

```
var totalPrice=Convert.ToDouble(lbl8_fruit.Text) +Convert.ToDouble(lbl10_drink.Text);
```

Comment: you are true , but how ?

Comment: Can you provide some more details.

Comment: for eg: from UI, var totalPrice=(int) lbl8_fruit.Text +(int)lbl10_drink.Text;

Comment: Inside the  lbl8_fruit.Text and lbl10_drink.Tex  are string values . and you write (int) befor them . the visualstudio gives me error for converting faild string to int . how should i convert string values to the int ?

Comment: var totalPrice=Convert.ToInt32(lbl8_fruit.Text)+Convert.ToInt32(lbl10_drink.Text);

Comment: are you trying to convert string like this "10" or "10.00" ?

Comment: can you explain about this code "var total= yourList.Sum(x=>x.Price);" ? for ex what means your list? what is x? what is =>     ?    my numbers are big . for ex 10,000 or 50,000

Comment: Check the updated answer. And "x' and "=>" are Lambda Expressions. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb397687.aspx and another link: http://codesamplez.com/programming/linq-lambda-expression-tutorial-c-sharp

Comment: and finaly how create list? i cant understand how i sould create list and sum all to show total price . I read the refrences but I did not exactly understand what you mean from list and filling in list

Comment: any one can help me?